# How to use both endpoints and compute engine in a single android app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am developing an android app using endpoints as the backend, however I wish to use braintree to implement payments in my app. This requires both a server and a client of which I only have the client. Since when using app engine and endpoints the virtual machines used are not very customizable and I can not run braintree on them, I was thinking if it would be possible to use endpoints and compute engine instead of endpoints and google app engine.

> In conclusion, is it possible to use endpoints with google compute
>   engine in order to implement server side code and customize the
>   virtual machines used?

Comment: Why do you say it is not possible to use Braintree in App Engine?

Comment: Because I can not find a solution. Please show me how! @Eric Simonton